# String format in RowDataBound

Tags: c#

I have a data reader to read the string from database in this format **2014-07**.

In querystring value I have always the string **2014-07** and I use the string format method to have in output **July 2014** in **RowDataBound**:

```
    //In RowDataBound
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["Month"]))
    {
        e.Row.Cells[1].Text = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0:MMMM yyyy}", 
                                             DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Month"));
    }
```

I use this code below for generate a new key in my **c# application** based on string **2014-07** or **July 2014**:

```
Label Month = (Label)row.FindControl("Month");

//generate a new key
DateTime dt;
DateTime.TryParseExact(Month.Text.ToString(), "MMMM yyyy",
               CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);

//Check "-" in string
if (Month.Text.ToString().IndexOf("-") == -1)
{
    string key = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM");
}
else
{
    string key = Month.Text.ToString();
}
```

If the string is **2014-07** and I don't convert the value **2014-07** to **July 2014** I have the correct output:

```
2014-07
```

If the string converted in **RowDataBound** is July 2014 I have the incorrect output:

```
0001-01
```

This is beginning to make me believe my structure as a whole is not correct.

What am I missing ?

What's wrong with the code?

I would greatly appreciate any help you can give me in working this problem.

**`Edit #1`**

I have tried print the value of gridview when the output is July 2014 and the ouput is empty, why?

```
Label Month = (Label)row.FindControl("Month");

Response.Write(Month.Text.ToString());
Response.End();
```

**`Edit #2`**

Code complete below:

```
protected void sendValueOfMonth(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
    string key;
    ImageButton ImgSend = (ImageButton)sender;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)Lotto_A.NamingContainer;
    Label Month = (Label)row.FindControl("Month");

    DateTime dt;
    DateTime.TryParseExact(Month.Text.ToString(), "MMMM yyyy",
                   CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);

    //Check "-" in string
    if (Month.Text.ToString().IndexOf("-") == -1)
    {
        key = dt.ToString("yyyy_MM");
    }
    else
    {
        key = Month.Text.ToString();
    }

    Response.Write(Month.Text.ToString() + "<br />");
    Response.Write(key.ToString());
 }


protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
      ImageButton ImgSend = (ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("ImgSend");
      Label Month = (Label)row.FindControl("Month");


        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["Month"]))
        {
            InitializeCulture();
            e.Row.Cells[1].Text = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0:MMMM yyyy}", DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Month"));
        }

    }
}


                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Send">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <center>
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImgSend" runat="server" OnClick="sendValueOfMonth" />
                            </center>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Month">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <center>
                                <asp:Label ID="Month" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Month").ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
                            </center>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: care to share the source of the front end also?

Comment: the front source? the gridView code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do anything else from your code behind. Try this:

```
<asp:Label ID="Month" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Month", "{0: yyyy-MM}").ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
```